# New tag request for [griddb]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

**Overview**

GridDB is an open source time series database for [IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things) and [big data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data).

At the time of this writing there are [29 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=griddb) related to GridDB and recently there was a request to create a GridDB tag on Stack Overflow:
https://github.com/griddb/griddb_nosql/issues/236

It seems that GridDB users do not yet have the 1,500 rep needed to create a new tag.

I think it would be beneficial to have the GridDB tag so the open source community can grow.

**Tag Info Suggestion**

[Excerpt]

GridDB is an open source time series database optimized for IoT and big data.

[Info]

GridDB is a highly scalable [time series database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database) best suited for Big Data and IoT. It is designed to handle time-sensitive IoT data across numerous sensors while maintaining consistency and durability.

GridDB Community Edition database server and client libraries are [open-sourced](https://github.com/griddb) under the [AGPL v3.0](https://github.com/griddb/griddb_nosql/blob/master/GNU-AGPL-3.0.txt) and [Apache](https://github.com/griddb/nodejs_client/blob/master/LICENSE) license respectively.

Useful Links

- [Frequently Asked Questions](https://griddb.net/en/faq/)
- [GridDB Documentation](https://griddb.net/en/docs/documents/1-1_what-is-griddb.php)
- [GridDB GitHub](https://github.com/griddb/griddb_nosql)
- [GridDB Developer Site](https://griddb.net/en/)
- [GridDB How-to Videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSEklgm-9fPf_BgMmv7bVgQ/videos)